# Google Maps JavaScript API でマーカーを識別できない

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Google Maps JavaScript API でどのマーカーがクリックされたかに応じて処理を変更したいのですが，マーカーを識別することができません．

ソースは以下のように書いています．locations は JSON データで，location['id'] には固有のIDと緯度経度が含まれていることは確認しました．markers はグローバル変数です．

```
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  var location = locations[i];
  if (!markers[location['id']]) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {lat: location['lat'], lng: location['lng']},
      map: map,
      title: '"' + location['name'] + '"'
    });
    markers[location['id']] = marker;
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(e) {
      console.log(location['id']);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決しました．

```
var location = locations[i]
```

上記の箇所で参照になっていて，表示している location['id'] も書き換わってしまっているということでした．for文内を別の関数にして実行したところうまくいきました．